# CSS: Element won't float next to siblings; works when out of flow

Tags: html, css, css-position

I want my sidenav to float over the green rectangle in the image below, and remain fixed as the user scrolls vertically.

I have a sidenav that floats just fine when I put it above the other siblings in my source code, but when I put it below these siblings it gets shunted to the bottom.

Here's the CSS for my sidenav:

```
.sidenav {
  float: right;
  position: fixed;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  width: 21em;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 60px;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: -2px 0px 8px #a7a7a7;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;    
}
```

When the `sidenav` element was above `background-rec`, `questions-container` etc, it floated in place just fine. But now it remains fixed to the bottom, and gets pushed down even more when new content loads.

I've also tried increasing the z-index.

Here's an image of the failing source order:

[image]

Comment: did you try to add `top:0` ?

Comment: float is useless if you use `position: fixed`

Comment: I think you need to provide some HTML here too, and also CSS for other elements that may be interfering with your sidenav. It's also not obvious in your picture which is the side nav or even what green rectangle you mean.

Comment: Becky's answer solved it, but your comments are useful - thank you, everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `top: 60px;` in your .sidenav class. I assume 60px looking at your `margin-top: 60px;` thinking that maybe you've tried to align the fixed div below the navbar. Otherwise `top: 0;` should fix your problem.